# count number of weekdays between two date strings in C99

Tags: c, date, c99

I have two date strings in the form *yyyy-mm-dd* , just like

```
const char* date_start = "2015-09-30";
const char* date_end   = "2015-10-03";
```

How do I calculate the number of weekdays (number of days which are neither Saturday nor Sunday) between the two dates? Dates where start and end day are equal can exists (the day count should be equal to 1 (workday) or 0 (weekend) then). All input dates are guaranteed to be valid (e.g. no 30th of February).

The solution need to work with C99 on OS X as well as Windows and independent of the system locale settings.

I would prefer to use as little external code (i.e. libraries or frameworks) as possible.

Comment: You have no code of your own. You only ask to someone do your homework for you.

Comment: @Morlacke no, it's not homework!? I looked through the [date and time functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_date_and_time_functions) and didn't find a way to accomplish what I need, so I asked

Comment: 1) [February 30, 1712](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_30#Swedish_calendar) 2) Convert to `struct tm`, call `mktime()` and examine `tm_wday`.  That with `difftime()` is all you need.

Comment: chux solution is perfect for linux - suggest u to research the equivalent on windows ( it will probably also be easy )

Comment: @amdixon they are all standard C functions that are also available on Windows. I suggest using [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to easily parse the dates into numbers, provided they follow the given format strictly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo Code

Form time structures

```
struct tm start = {0};
start.tm_year = 2105-1900;
start.tm_mon = 9-1;
start.tm_mday = 30;
start.tm_isdst = 0;
struct tm end = ...
```

Form time number and set tm_wday field

```
time_t tstart = mktime(&start);
time_t tend = mktime(&end);
```

Find day difference

```
double day_diff = difftime(&tend, &tstart)/(24.0*60*60);
```

Some magic per weekday (left for OP)

```
numweekdays = ((long)day_diff/7)*5 + foo(start->tm_wday, end->tm_wday);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. convert date-strings to something more handable, like "long date since 1.1.1970", if that suits your use case; or "struct tm"
2. calculate the difference in days (end minus start plus one)
3. for each complete week inside the difference (> 7) add 5 weekdays/2 weekends
4. calculate the weekday-status for the rest (at least 6) days and add them accordinly